# Practice AP CS Test

Tags: java

I've got a student studying for the AP CS test (he takes it next week). I was hired mid/end year to basically be a long term sub for the rest of the school year for these IT classes. I don't know enough about java or programming to explain to him why the answer to this practice test problem is B and not A (according to the answer sheet).

I'm hoping this might be a decent place to get an explanation I can take to him...

```
/** Precondition: arr contains only positive values. 
*/
public static void doSome(int[]arr, int lim)
{
  int v = 0;
  int k = 0;
  while (k < arr.length && arr[k] < lim)
  {
    if (arr[k] > v)
      {
        v = arr[k]; /* Statement S */
      }
  k++;  /* Statement T */
  }
}
```

Assume that *doSome* is called and executes without error. Which of the following are possible combinations for the value of lim, the number of times Statement S is executed, and the number of times Statement T is executed?

possible combinations for the value of lim

[image: Image of possible combinations for the value of lim]

(A) I only

(B) II only

(C) III only

(D) I and III only

(E) II and III only

Comment: whats in the array

Comment: @user1490835 positive integers, the question specifies this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`III` is not a valid combination because you can't execute *S* more times than you execute *T*.
*From a test-taking perspective:* In this problem, this is the most important insight because figuring this out immediately knocks out 3 options and takes you down to a 50/50 shot on a guess.

`I` is not a valid combination because the array contains only positive values, all of which are > 0, so the conditional `if(arr[k]>v)` must return `true` at least once, meaning that *S* is executed at least once if the `while` loop body gets executed at least once.  In option `I`, statement *T* (also in the body of the `while` loop) is executed 5 times, so *S* must be executed at least once.

`II` is a valid combination of values.
*From a test-taking perspective:* It's not worth taking the time to prove this (e.g. by providing sample inputs that produce this combination), as process of elimination has already taken you down to one answer.

Therefore, option B, `II only`, is the correct answer.

Props to the AP test question writer.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation of each option. This will be really helpful! I haven't known how else to help him prepare very well except to have him take practice tests and go back and research why he got the ones incorrect that he did. Fingers crossed for Monday.

Comment: @MsAudra that is a great method of preparation.  It's also good to start as early as possible in that prep (the same amount of practice is more effective when distributed over time than when crammed into just before the test), and be well rested with a good breakfast on test day.  Best of luck to your student on the test!