# According to this mock Java class, wouldn't the maximum value of k be 1?

Tags: java

[image: Took a quiz today, I don't think that any of the answers apply]

I was taking a Java quiz today, and I did not understand one of the questions. Could someone explain the answer to me?

Also, I am not the best at "executing" Java code in my head, but the code I write is just fine. Does anyone else have this problem?

Comment: Is there another place I can ask for programming help where the people are a little more understanding?

Comment: Perhaps http://www.CodeRanch.com. The *Stack Overflow* site has a specific purpose: Ask questions narrowly focused on a specific technical programming issue that is likely to have an identifiable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question was asked 4 years ago for this exact same quiz and was answered there.

[Practice AP CS Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36904173/practice-ap-cs-test)

I find that the best way to research something is to take a snippet of a piece of the quiz, paste it in to google and search. You will immediately find answers and similar questions. Incidentally it is also a great way to do debugging research.

Comment: This is not the exact same question because in this version, `k++` is outside of the `while` loop, whereas in the version you linked, `k++` is inside the loop. It seems likely that the question was *supposed* to be the same as the one you linked, but someone made a mistake transcribing it.

Comment: @kaya3 That's what confused me!

Comment: Thanks for this, I thought all of these questions were written by the teacher themselves lol

Comment: No worries man. Again, google is your friend for this stuff. I think people get annoyed on this and most help websites when they think a person asking for help hasn't done their due diligence in researching the problem themselves.